# Firebase Data Modeling (NoSQL Models) for Clinic app

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, nosql, data-modeling

Any suggestions are welcomed and appreciated.

Trying to build a Flutter app for managing multiple Clinics, Patients and their appointments.

The app has the following **entities and dependencies**:

1. Every clinic is separated from another clinic.
2. Users (clinic staff) added by the admin (me manually) can access certain clinic info.
3. Users should be able to sign in by email and password only, they will be directed automatically to the correct clinic.
4. Clinic has patients and appointments.
5. App has a feature of searching patients by name.
6. App has a feature of showing future, past or present appointments.(also over a certain period of time).

**NOTE: The database should be optimized for minimum reads/writes for commercial usage.**

```
Users (collection)
    - user1_id (document)
        name,
        email,
        clinicReference(id),
    - user2_id ....
    - user3_id ....
        

Clinics (collection)

    - clinic1_id (document)

        Users_allowed_access (array)
            - user3_id
            - user4_id
    
        Patients (collection)
            - patient1_id (document)
                name,
                date_of_birth,
                phoneNumber,
                Appointments_of_patient1 (collection)
                    - appointment1_id (doc)
                        dateTime,
                        medicalInfo (map),
                    - appointment2_id

            - patient2_id (document) ....
            - patient3_id (document) ....

        Appointments (collection)
        // I'm not sure if this should exist //
        // Or how it should be organized //


    - clinic2_id ....
    - clinic3_id ....
```

How number 6 can be implemented so that The user should be able to query (for example) *"All the appointments of the clinic for the past week"* .. Results should contain (name of patient, dateTime of appointment, reference to the original appointment so that He can access medical info).

Comment: What's your question? It's not clear what sort of help you're looking for.  Asking for "free resources" is off topic for Stack Overflow, which means this question is likely to get [closed](https://overflow.tips/why-question-closed) as "Seeking recommendations for books, tools, software libraries, and more".

Comment: Did you try something that doesn't work the way you expect? We can't really tell you what your app's appointment data looks like or how you need to query them.

Comment: @DougStevenson The user should be able to query (for example) "All the appointments of the clinic for the past week" .. Results should contain (name of patient, dateTime of appointment, reference to the original appointment so that He can access medical info).

Comment: OK, that information should be in your question. It would help if you also make an attempt to solve the problem and show what you tried that didn't work the way you expected.

Comment: Please edit your question and add the information Doug asked for, and please also respond using @.